# Does anyone know what this tool is specifically used for?

Tags: hand-tools

This is some sort of file obviously to sharpen something but I have no ideas

[image: end on view of tool]

[image: one side of tool]

[image: the other side of tool]

Comment: If nothing else, it might work as a card scraper jointer. https://www.leevalley.com/en-us/shop/tools/sharpening/jigs-mounts-and-rests/32631-veritas-jointer-edger?item=05M0701

Comment: I rotated the images so they were all right-side-up just to make it easier on everyone's brains. You may want to provide larger images so they can be zoomed in on so people can see any manufacturer's marks on them. It might be helpful to provide any lettering on the tools, too.

Answer (score 3):

It's to file the teeth of a handsaw to the same length, before using other files to actually sharpen the teeth.

Can also be used (but not made specifically for) to file the edge of a scraper.

Here's a link to a home-made version, showing use: https://www.lumberjocks.com/mafe/blog/28887